# Build issue when using <cmath> with android ndk

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk, cmath

I have a simple file `stlTest2.cpp` like this:

```
#include <jni.h>

#include <cmath>


bool isnan (void);
```

There is something more complicated in some code I am porting.  My question is this.  Why would this work when building using GCC outside of the NDK, but not with using the NDK?  There error it gives is this:

```
jni/stlTest2.cpp:6: error: expected unqualified-id before 'sizeof'
jni/stlTest2.cpp:6: error: expected ')' before 'sizeof'
```

The immediate reason for this is that `math.h` (included via `<cmath>`) defines `isnan` as a macro.  Why is the build outside of the ndk not including the `#define` from `math.h`, but this is?  If I comment out the includes in the code, all is fine, but that is not acceptable as this problem repeats itself.... a lot.

Comment: Why do you declare `isnan` with an incompatible type?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In $ndk\sources\cxx-stl\gnu-libstdc++\libs\armeabi\include\bits\c++config.h (change armeabi to whatever is appropriate) change this:

```
/* #undef _GLIBCXX_USE_C99_MATH */
```

to

```
#define _GLIBCXX_USE_C99_MATH 1
```

Then clean and build your project again.

Answer (score 4):

The `isnan` macro was added in C99. In C++11 it was added as a function in the `std` namespace, overloaded for `float` and `double` and `long double` (so a typical `<cmath>` header, such as your non-NDK GCC is probably using, might have something like this:

```
#undef isnan

inline bool isnan(float ...) { ... }

inline bool isnan(double ...) { ... }

inline bool isnan(long double ...) { ... }
```

), but apparently the NDK hasn't gotten the memo, and is still providing the C99 macro as a convenience. (`isnan` was never a macro in C++, but before TR1 added `std::tr1::isnan`, there wasn't really a C++ alternative, so multiple C++ compilers provided the C99 macro.)

Do you need to be able to use the compiler-provided `isnan` or `std::isnan`? If not, then you can just change this:

```
#include <cmath>
```

to this:

```
#include <cmath>

#undef isnan
```

(and similarly for any other problematic macros, provided you don't need them).

Comment: I can do that and started to do it, but the code is full of such.  I was wondering if there was a way to get android to use a different, more up to date cmath.  If not, I will accept your answer.  I already voted it up.  Thanks.  Btw same issue with a lot of math.h macros, but same solution should work.

Comment: Found the way to fix this.  See my answer.